# Exception when receiving empty response from server (Retrofit2, LiveData, RxJava2)

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

The problem I am struggling with only happens when I recieve an empty response from the server. If the response is **not** empty it works like a charm. Even though it doesn't work with the empty response the app does not crash! It simply skips the code in the observe part. After that there are no further instructions so it only shows the loading circle forever.

I changed a bit of code in my project to be able to see why exactly it crashes and found this:

> E/MainApplication: Undeliverable Fatal Error
>
> io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred

Those 2 are as follows:

> ComposedException 1 :
>         android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>
> ComposedException 2 :
>         java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Here is the code that I use to make the API-Call (Some identifiers changed because of privacy). I tried using RxJava's onError, onErrorReturn and try+catch but nothing catches the exception. I read something about LiveData not delivering exceptions but I'm not that familiar with it.

In the View:

```
liveData = viewModel.getDataFromApi(displayedCategory!!.id, getString(R.string.lang_code))
liveData?.observe(this, Observer<Array<Data>> {...}
```

In my ViewModel:

```
fun getDataFromApi(categoryId: Int, language: String): LiveData<Array<Data>> {
        return LiveDataReactiveStreams
            .fromPublisher(
                repository.getDataFromApi(categoryId, language)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()))
    }
```

In my Repository:

```
fun getDataFromApi(categoryId: Int, language: String): Flowable<Array<Data>> {
        return rfService.getDataOfCategory(categoryId, language)
            .doOnNext {
                Log.d("Repository", "Fetching ${it.size} data from API")
                //adding the language to the question for DB calls
                for (element in it) {
                    element.language = language
                }
                insertQuestionsInDb(it)
            }
            .onErrorReturnItem(emptyArray())
    }
```

Retrofit Service looks like this:

```
@GET("data/categories/{category_id}/questions/{lang}")
    Flowable<Data[]> getQuestionsOfCategory(@Path("category_id") int categoryId, @Path("lang") String lang);
```

I'm at a total loss how to catch the error and react to it so the observe function doesn't crash.